# Hankel transform of arbitrary order of $f(r)=1$

Tags: dirac-delta, integral-transforms

The Hankel transform of order $\nu$ of a function $f(r)$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}
F_\nu(k) = \int_0 ^\infty r dr f(r) J_\nu(kr ),
\end{equation*}
where $J_v$ is a Bessel function of the first kind of order $\nu$.

I am interested in the scenario where $f(r)=1$, where one must be careful about how to consider convergence. For instance it is [commonly cited in the literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Some_Hankel_transform_pairs) that for $f(r)=1$ we have $F_0(k) = \delta(k)/k$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

Is there a generalisation of this to arbitrary $\nu$, i.e., what is $F_\nu(k)$ for $f(r)=1$? (My primary interest is in the case of $\nu=2$.) If there is no exact answer, is there anyway to approach this numerically given that the answer will likely involve a Dirac delta?

---

Motivation:

This question arises in the context of a problem in physics. In particular, I require the Fourier transform of $f(r,\theta) = e^{2 i \theta}$, written in polar coordinates, which can be reduced to solving the Hankel transform of $f(r)=1$ with $\nu=2$.

Comment: The table below on your link has $r^s$ for arbitrary $s$.

Comment: With Mathematica `Limit[HankelTransform[r^w, r, k, \[Nu]], w -> 0] // 
  FunctionExpand // PowerExpand` gives: $$\frac{\nu }{k^2}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to proceed is to examine the Inverse Second-Order Transform for $F(k)=\frac1{k^2}$.  Proceeding, we find that the Second-Order Inverse Hankel Transform of $F$ is

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{H_2}^{-1}\{F\}(r)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{J_2(kr)}{k^2}\,k\,dk\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{J_2(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty\\\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left.\left(-\frac{J_1(x)}{x}\right)\right|_\varepsilon^L\tag1\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

where in arriving at $(1)$, we used the recurrence relationship $J_2(x)=\frac{J_1(x)}{x}-J_1'(x)$, along with $J_1(x)=x/2+O(x^2)$.

Therefore, the Second-Order Inverse Hankel Transform of $\frac2{k^2}$ is equal to $1$.  And in distribution, we must have

$$\mathscr{H_2}\{1\}(k)=\frac2{k^2}$$